# can anyone help me out with this :Variable does not exist: ChildOpps

Tags: apex

Apex:

```
public class My_ChildOpp_Task {
    public Account acc{set;get;}
    public My_ChildOpp_Task(ApexPages.StandardController std){
        acc=(Account)std.getRecord();

    }
    public List<Opportunity> getChildRecord(){
        return [select Id,name,amount,stageName from Opportunity where AccountId =: acc.Id and (isWon=true or isClosed=false)];
    }
    private void createTaskOnChildOpps(){
        List<Task> TaskToInsert=new List<Task>();
        for(Opportunity opp: ChildOpps ){
            if(!opp.isClosed){
                TaskToInsert.add(
                    new Task(
                        WhatId = opp.Id,
                        OwnerId = opp.OwnerId,
                        ActivityDate = Date.today() + 3,
                        Status = 'Not-Started',
                        Subject = 'Send follow-up email to primary contact'));
            }
        }

        if(TaskToInsert.size()>0){
            insert TaskToInsert;
        }

                }
    public PageReference save() {
        pageReference page=new pageReference();
                       if (acc.Rating == 'Hot') {
                            createTaskOnChildOpps();
                                      }
                                       update acc;
                                         return page('/' + acc.Id);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have no variable or identifier called `ChildOpps`. In Apex, you must declare all variables you intend to use.

If your intention was to iterate over the return value of the method `getChildRecord()`, you have to actually call the method in your `for` loop, where you have `ChildOpps` written.

This is a great example of a general rule in *how to get started with debugging*. First, carefully read the error message and try to understand what it's telling you about your code as the system understands it. Here, it's telling you that it does not have a match for the name `ChildOpps`.

Then, combine that understanding with the intention you possess for the code itself to locate a first pointer towards a solution. Sometimes, syntax errors can cause messages to be shown to you that don't make a lot of sense, but draw your attention to the right area to understand why your code won't save. Here, though, the situation is pretty straightforward, and all you have to do to solve it is do what the compiler is asking of you.